# Resolve Route Server Side in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Just as you figure out the route when the browser hits the webpage in Rails, how would you resolve it on the **server side**?

For example I want to return a URL to a RESTful resource called Bookmark in an API call and want to return the 'show' action of it, and I know that:

```
Bookmark id: 12
```

Then I want to resolve it to a string:

```
'/bookmarks/edit/12'
```

so that I can get this from my Model for example.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everywhere in the views/controllers you can use [route helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to DRY up route references.

In models, you'll need to explicitly call the route helper like so.

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_bookmark_path(id) # => '/bookmarks/12/edit'

When using the default resourceful route generator method in routes.rb like

resource :bookmarks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand - your server is the thing that's making all of those routes work - the client's browser isn't figuring out what the route is - you application is doing it.

The paths to your resources are available as helper methods at all times (at least within the controllers, and views). As such, you should return the string as the body of a response in one of your actions, in the controller that's handling your API calls.

Check your `rake routes` on the command line, and you'll see a list of them. In the case of your example above, it would likely be called `edit_bookmark_path(12)`